# for aninado desde python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, geolocalización

Amigos necesito una ayuda que me esta quebrando la cabeza, resulta que estoy creando un proyecto con coordenadas.

-> Tengo un modelos con datos de latitud y longitud separados asi:

```
from crum import get_current_user
from django.db import models
from django.forms import model_to_dict
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from applications.models import BaseModel
from applications.customers.models import *

# Create your models here.
class Pdv(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150, verbose_name="Nombre del PDV:")
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Dirección:")
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Razón Social:')
    pdv_code =  models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='codigo de PDV:', null=True, blank=True)
    pdv_channel = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Canal de PDV:')
    chain_pdv = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Cadena:', null=True, blank=True)
    time_pdv = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Tiempo en PDV:', null=True, blank=True)
    frequency_pdv = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Frecuencia PDV:')
    latitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Latitud:")
    longitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Longitud:")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Ciudad:')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Departamento:')
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Cliente:")
```

-> Tengo una vista que funciona con ajax la cual envia unos datos para realizar un filtro en la query, asi:

```
list_pdv_client = Pdv.objects.filter(customers_id=request.POST['idclient']).order_by('-latitude')

# Nuevo codigo utilizando la funcion de medir la distancia y ordenar los pdv
pdv_referenc = Pdv.objects.filter(customers_id=request.POST['idclient']).order_by('-latitude')[0]
```

Ya con el contexto que les comente ahora si, primero necesito con los pdv (puntos de venta) ya filtrados ahora necesito medir la distancia que hay entre el punto de referencia con todo demás puntos de la query, y ordenarlos por orden menor a mayor distancia:

```
pdvs_kms = list()

for x in list_pdv_client:
   km_dist = calc_distance(pdv_referenc.latitude, pdv_referenc.longitude, x.latitude, x.longitude)
   pdvs_kms.append({'pdv': x, "distance":km_dist})

pdvs_kms = sorted(pdvs_kms, key=lambda p: p['distance'])
```

Ahora itero los pdv para ir sumando los tiempos que de cada pdv que tiene almacenado en la query, y genero una varible como inicio y le asigno el mismo `pdv_referenc`.
con una condicion valido si se cumple una cantidad de tiempo o si esta dentro del tiempo creo una nueva lista, si es falsa la condición entonces cambio el `pdv_referenc` al pdv actual de la iteración, y necesito que se vuelva a medir la distancia con el nuevo `pdv_referenc` sin tener en cuenta los puntos ya iterados, y volver a organizar los pdv por distancia de menor a mayor distancia, que el for se reinicie para continuar iterando la nueva lista de pdv tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
pdv_conects = []
cant_gen = 1
t_h = td()
for pd in pdvs_kms:
  inicia = pdv_referenc
  # Sumamos los pdv hasta llegar a una persona
  h = dt.strptime(pd["pdv"].time_pdv, "%H:%M:%S").time()
  t_h += td(hours=h.hour, minutes=h.minute, seconds=h.second) * int(pd["pdv"].frequency_pdv)
  t_h += td(minutes=int(translado))

  mint = t_h.total_seconds() / 60
  vals = mint/11520

  # Validamos cuanto de ocupación en una persona
  if vals <= float(1.0):
     pdv_conects.append([[inicia["pdv"].latitude, inicia["pdv"].longitude], [pd["pdv"].latitude, pd["pdv"].longitude]])

  else:
      inicia = pd
      t_h = td()
      cant_gen += 1
```

necesito ya ayuda para poder hacer que el for se reinicie y volver a generar la medicion de distancia y la organizacion de la lista y que el for continue con la nueva lista o cual seria la mejor opcion para resolver este problema, les agradezco de corazon la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Es recomendable que para los valores que almacena la variable `time_pdv` en el modelo `Pdv` uses [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) en lugar de `CharField` y para las coordenadas puedes usar `DecimalField` asi:

```
lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Tambien puedes usar `namedtuple`

```
from collections import namedtuple
coords = namedtuple("Coords", ['x', 'y'])
coords(1,2)
Coords(x=1, y=2)
coords(1.235445,2.2345345)
```

esto podría evitar posibles errores al manejar los datos generados por el modelo.

La iteración en las filas/columnas de un *DataFrame* no es muy recomendable por asuntos de consumo de recursos ya que podría tomar tiempo innecesario hacer operaciones que son posibles gracias a métodos como `iterrows`, `apply` o una simple conversión de arreglos `Numpy`, en este caso he definido una funcion **`validar_ocupacion`** que toma 3 parametros, `pd, pd_inicia, cnt`, los cuales son: el `pd` actual el cual se esta iterando, `pd_inicia` o `inicia` y `cnt`, para llevar la cuenta de `cant_gen`, entonces es pasado `inicia` ya que al chequear si es menor o igual a `float(1.0)` entonces, recursivamente llamara la función nuevamente usando `pd_inicia`, hay que tener cuidado en no llevar el programa a una ejecución infinita ya que si nunca aserta la condición `<=float(1.0)` entonces nunca terminara, si es ejecutado correctamente entonces devolverá un arreglo con 3 elementos.

```
pdv_conects = []
cant_gen = 1
t_h = td()

def validar_ocupacion(pd, pd_inicia, cnt=0):
    # Sumamos los pdv hasta llegar a una persona
    h = dt.strptime(pd["pdv"].time_pdv, "%H:%M:%S").time()
    t_h += td(hours=h.hour, minutes=h.minute, seconds=h.second) * int(pd["pdv"].frequency_pdv)
    t_h += td(minutes=int(translado))

    mint = t_h.total_seconds() / 60
    vals = mint/11520

    return [pd, vals, cnt] if vals <= float(1.0) else validar_ocupacion(pd_inicia, pd, cnt+1)
    
for pd in pdvs_kms:
    inicia = pdv_referenc

    # Validamos cuanto de ocupación en una persona
    result = validar_ocupacion(pd, pd_inicia)
    pdv_conects.append([[inicia["pdv"].latitude, inicia["pdv"].longitude], [result[0]["pdv"].latitude, result[0]["pdv"].longitude]])
```

Answer (score 0):

No me quedo muy claro lo que pides,  aunque por lo que entendí aquí unas recomendaciones.

- Puedes incluir un método que incluya el ciclo For,
  de esa manera lo puedes estar llamando cada que lo necesites

No index son elementos que no incluiras en los siguientes calculos
Se declara vacio por default

```
def distanciaspdv(self, origen, pdv, noindex=[] ):
```

Quitamos los elementos de una lista

```
self.newpdv = [elem for elem in pdv if elem not in no index]
```

El for con las opreaciones que necesitas

```
for d in self.newpdv:
```

Restar las distancias
Medir tiempos.
Actualizar noindex.
Utiliza zip(distacias, tiempos)    **OPCIONAL**
para retornar algo así

```
result = [(d1,t1),(d2,t2),(d3,t3), etc. ]
```

ordenar o realiza un filtrado de result

```
return Result
```

No sé si el algoritmo A* te sea de ayuda.